# PHP MySQLi : Uninitializaed String offset

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

I'm trying to use a foreach result to display some reviews, but seems not working, must to print the IDs and text for each review found on database contain the review ID.

```
$revnr = $_GET['id'];

$result_rev = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM  `reviews` WHERE  `ID_prod` = " .$revnr. " LIMIT 0 , 30");
$row_revs = mysqli_fetch_all($result_rev);

  if ($row_revs == NULL) {
     print '<p class="text-center">No Reviews!</p>';
  } else {
     foreach($row_revs as $row_rev){
        $id_r = $row_rev['2'];
        $id_c = $qls -> user_info[$id_r];
        $ID_review   = $row_rev['0'];
        $ID_prod     = $row_rev['1'];
        $ID_user     = $id_c;
        $review      = $row_rev['3'];
        $stars       = $row_rev['4'];
             [...]               
  }
}

mysqli_free_result($result_rev);
?>
```

Using mysqli_fetch_all I can fetch all and put in array.

Comment: see here, `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_rev);`. You're fetching the row as an associative array, not as a numeric array.

Comment: Hi @RajdeepPaul thanks for the reply, i've tried to change it to `mysqli_fetch_array` but nothing changed

Comment: Remove the quotes around `0`, `1` etc. It should be `$row_rev[0]`, `$row_rev[1]`...like that.

Comment: Put here the all error output.

Comment: Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 2 in /home/ubuntu/workspace/views/product.php on line 105 Call Stack: 0.0015 237176 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:0 0.1947 361208 2. include('/home/ubuntu/workspace/core/switch.php') /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:14 0.1954 364592 3. include('/home/ubuntu/workspace/views/product.php') /home/ubuntu/workspace/core/switch.php:5 etc...

Comment: Solution to this is to use `mysqli_fetch_all` instead of fetch array, i got this solution in another board cause i've not received reply here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) which will return your results in an associative array. So you would read the results using the fieldname as the key. For example, if your table has the field `id`, you would access it using `$row_rev['id'];`.

If you want to use the index you can use [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) - also note that you don't need to quote the numbers when fetching the result, e.g.

```
$id_r = $row_rev[2];
```

Comment: i've tried to change and cut off the quotes, but nothing changed, i'm thinking that the problem is the query but using var_dump i got this (class mysqli_result#14 (5) { public $current_field => int(0) public $field_count => int(5) public $lengths => array(5) { [0] => int(1) [1] => int(2) [2] => int(1) [3] => int(66) [4] => int(1) } public $num_rows => int(2) public $type => int(0) })

Comment: The `while` loop you have in the question now looks like you're closer to a working solution. Maybe add `mysqli_num_fields($result_rev);` to verify how many rows are being returned by your query if you aren't seeing them all.

Comment: i'm using it with var_dump and result as int(5) ,using `foreach ($row_revs as $row_rev)` it echo 10 rows instead of 2